# Convert a string to a callable function in Python

Tags: python

I want to take written function (string) from a user input and convert it to a callable function in Python.
How to achieve it despite any security concerns?

Example (**string**):

""" **def test(): \n print('success') \n return 'success'** """

**I want to call / evaluate the said string by calling test() and make it print to the console.**

Comment: use `value or func = eval(some code string)`, you might need `value = func(params) `afterwards.

Comment: [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is safer.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp literal eval is for literal data only (like `53.136`, or `(1, 2, 3)`, or `{"x": 3}`). You cannot parse function definitions with it.

Comment: `eval` evaluates expressions; you need `exec` to execute a `def` statement.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I tried using a node generated by ast.parse before the ast.literal_eval, but got a ValueError: malformed node or string. That was using indentation. With no indentation I got indentation error.

Comment: As an aside, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @LeiYang, it seems eval itself isn't capable of parsing the string correctly.

Comment: @ddejohn, there is a prototype page with an html text box we want new learners to write down the functions without any third party tool (or support).

Answer (score 2):

When appropriate, this is a job for the [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) function.

```
>>> exec("""def test(): \n print('success') \n return 'success' """, globals())
>>> test()
success
'success'
```

Comment: Why should one use exec instead of compile? Thanks!

Comment: in short, `exec` is shorter. by `compile` you need another invoke statement.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, using the compile method combined with eval or exec：

```
a = compile("""def test(): \n print('success') \n return 'success' """, "", "exec")
eval(a)

test()
```

Comment: Why compile should be picked instead of exec? Thanks!

Comment: Both are possible, but I think this way is more concise and less error-prone